# Access JSON data after creating jQuery elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm receiving JSON data from an API and am creating jQuery elements and appending them to a list.

How can I make it so that when I click on one of the HTML elements that were created, I can log that element's original JSON data it was created from to the console?

```
cards.forEach(function (card) {
    var $newCard = $("<li>" + card.name + "</li>");
    $newCard.click(function () {
        // gives me the HTML, but I don't see the properties of the
        // object it was created from.
        console.log(this);
    });
    cardsContainer.append($newCard);
});
```

I'm guessing I could add an `onclick` function right inside the string HTML? Is there a way to do it from the JavaScript instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access card, as that is inside a function closure..

```
cards.forEach(function (card) {
  var $newCard = $("<li>" + card.name + "</li>");
  $newCard.click(function () {
      console.log(this); //will be the LI
      console.log(card); //this will be the card
  });
  cardsContainer.append($newCard);
});
```

Comment: Ugh, man I feel dumb. No wonder I couldn't find answers anywhere on this... :P

Comment: No need to feel dumb, coming from Delphi / C++, took me some time to get my head around closures.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you are looking something like this:

```js
var cardsContainer = $('#container'),
  cards = [{
    name: "One"
  }, {
    name: "Two"
  }, {
    name: "Three",
    test: "asd"
  }]
cards.forEach(function(card) {
  var $newCard = $("<li>" + card.name + "</li>").data('extra', card).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log($(this).data('extra'));
  });

  cardsContainer.append($newCard);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="container"></ul>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I tried the `.data()` method but couldn't get it to work. I forgot to use `$(this).data()` instead of just `this.data()`.

Comment: Like my answer showed, why not just access card.. it's inside a closure, no need of jquery.data..

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the entire object inside your new `$newCard` variable.

For example:

```
var $newCard = $("<li>" + card.name + "</li>");
$newCard.data("myOriginalObject", card);
$newCard.click(function () {
    // Should now print the original object correctly
    console.log($(this).data("myOriginalObject"));
});
```